# When is an IllegalAccessException appropriate?

Tags: java, exception

Say you have a class called `Timer`. When a user tries to call the method `Timer#start()`, the code checks if the timer has already been started. If it has, then it can't start it again. Now, say this class is a part of a library/API. The developer can't know that the method isn't being called inappropriately, so they want to bring attention to any improper calls. The two ways to do so would be to a) print a simple error message (so-and-so has called a method inappropriately), or b) throw an exception.

In my opinion, the exception that would make the most sense is an IllegalAccessException, though this isn't its intention as stated by Sun. However, I've seen it used in cases that have nothing to do with visibility and are simply throwing it to call attention to a bad call. My question is, would this situation call for (haha, pun) said exception, or is there a better one suited to it? Or, would it be best to create a new one or to simply print an error line?

Comment: Did you get it mixed up with [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)? `IllegalAccessException` makes zero sense for this.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, it's quite possible that I'm misremembering the exception I've seen in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement it seems `IllegalStateException` is more appropriate. As your class is managing some state of the Timer.

From Java Doc for `IllegalStateException` :

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or
>     inappropriate time.  In other words, the Java environment or
>     Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested
>     operation.

From Java doc for `IllegalAccessException`, it says:

> An IllegalAccessException is thrown when an application tries
>     to reflectively create an instance (other than an array),
>     set or get a field, or invoke a method, but the currently
>     executing method does not have access to the definition of
>     the specified class, field, method or constructor.

so, `IllegalAccessException` is not at all appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This condition very clearly doesn't match the semantics of `IllegalAccessException`, but it sounds like an exact fit for `IllegalStateException`.